# What is the right type for validations when implementing express-validator imperative validations?

Tags: typescript, express, express-validator

Trying to implement [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator)’s [imperative validations](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/running-imperatively.html) in TypeScript, but can’t find the type for `validations`.

```js
// can be reused by many routes
const validate = validations => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    await Promise.all(validations.map(validation => validation.run(req)));

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
      return next();
    }

    res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  };
};

app.post('/api/create-user', validate([
  body('email').isEmail(),
  body('password').isLength({ min: 6 })
]), async (req, res, next) => {
  // request is guaranteed to not have any validation errors.
  const user = await User.create({ ... });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! The type is `ValidationChain[]`.